Started receiving "This IP can't make requests for that application." for all Facebook requests coming from Heroku app
Starting December 21st all API requests coming from Heroku get blocked by FB. Requests coming from local machine with whitelisted IP continue to work. Ran a script to identify Heroku IP and added that IP manually to whitelist but this is not scalable since Heroku assigns IPs dynamically. Has anyone else started seeing this issue recently? Any feedback from FB?
